# Cannot insert or create in mongodb using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Why is it that I can't create in mongodb using nodejs.
I can insert data using mongo shell.
But if I insert data using nodejs with mongoose. There's an error.

```
    { MongoError: not authorized on node-angular to execute command { insert: "users", documents: [ { firstName: "Angelo", lastName: "Castillo", password: "password", email: "asdad@gmail.com", _id: ObjectId('59d
70936284aad66d4d1207b'), messages: [], __v: 0 } ], ordered: false }
    at Function.MongoError.create (C:\Users\Desktop\Angular\Training\mean\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\error.js:31:11)
    at C:\Users\Desktop\Angular\Training\mean\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:497:72
    at authenticateStragglers (C:\Users\Desktop\Angular\Training\mean\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:443:16)
    at Connection.messageHandler (C:\Users\Desktop\Angular\Training\mean\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:477:5)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Desktop\Angular\Training\mean\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:331:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:547:20)
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'not authorized on node-angular to execute command { insert: "users", documents: [ { firstName: "test", test: "lastname", password: "password", email: "asdad@gmail.com", _id: ObjectId(\'59d7
0936284aad66d4d1207b\'), messages: [], __v: 0 } ], ordered: false }',
  ok: 0,
  errmsg: 'not authorized on node-angular to execute command { insert: "users", documents: [ { firstName: "test", test: "Castillo", password: "password", email: "asdad@gmail.com", _id: ObjectId(\'59d70
936284aad66d4d1207b\'), messages: [], __v: 0 } ], ordered: false }',
  code: 13,
  codeName: 'Unauthorized' }
```

Here is my user in node-angular db.

```
> show users
{
        "_id" : "node-angular.nodeangular",
        "user" : "nodeangular",
        "db" : "node-angular",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "dbOwner",
                        "db" : "node-angular"
                },
                {
                        "role" : "readWrite",
                        "db" : "node-angular"
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: I fixed my problem. I just didn't include my username and password in my connection.
mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:password@127.0.0.1:27017/node-angular', {useMongoClient: true});

Comment: then describe the fix as an answer to your question and in the future I recommend setting up a testing suite to test your connection before you dive deep into development.